# How to force Python to save all rows

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on this code, trying to read a csv file and save as JSON.
The issue is, only last row is being saved as JSON. The iteration happens but not saving all previous rows.

Here is the code:

```
def make_json(myFile, jsonFilePath):
data2 = {}
with open('CSVFile.csv', encoding='utf-8') as csvf:
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf)
    for rows in csvReader:
        data2 = rows
        with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf:
            jsonf.write(simplejson.dumps([data2], indent=4))
```

Comment: You keep creating a new file *on every iteration*. Either open the file in append mode or better yet, don't open and close a file on each iteration

Comment: you can't write JSON line by line. It creates `mulitline-JSON`, not `JSON`. You have to read all data, create one object in memory and write this object at once.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue is that you're opening the file on every row and just writing that row. and since you're using `'w'` in the open function, anything that you write in the file will overwrite the entire file.

One simple way to fix this is to change the `'w'` to append mode with `'a'`, you can read more on different modes [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#open).

But this way it won't be valid json, it would just be json on each line.

The other way is to collect the whole cvs into one variable and then write that:

```
def make_json(myFile, jsonFilePath):
    with open('CSVFile.csv', encoding='utf-8') as csvf:
        csvReader = csv.reader(csvf)
        data = [row for row in csvReader]
        with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf:
            jsonf.write(simplejson.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Comment: shorter: `data = list(csvReader)`

Answer (score -1):

You should create a single file at the end - your solution is overwriting the file on each loop:

```
def make_json(myFile, jsonFilePath):
    data = []
    with open(myFile, encoding='utf-8') as csvf:
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf)
        for rows in csvReader:
            data.append(rows)

    with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf:
        json.dump(data, jsonf, indent=4)
```

Comment: shorter: `data = list(csvReader)`